# What are the venues where FC Barcelona used to play in its early days?

Tags: football, venues

I was reading about history of Camp Nou on the [official website of FC Barcelona](https://www.fcbarcelona.com/club/facilities/card/camp-nou-the-history). First paragraph reads:

> In the early days, the club constantly switched between different grounds. In the second stage, the club was consolidated by finding a permanent home at Les Corts. And the third stage, and the construction of the Camp Nou, reflects the expansion and grandeur of the club on a global scale.

Searching on the web found only two venues [Camp de la Indústria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_de_la_Ind%C3%BAstria) and [Camp de Les Corts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_de_Les_Corts) before [Camp Nou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_Nou). As the website says they switched between different grounds before construction of Les Corts.

What are the other venues where FC Barcelona used to play in its early years of existence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three stadium *[Camp de la Indústria, Camp de Les Corts, and Camp Nou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Barcelona#Stadia)* are the major ones but before FC Barcelona moved to Camp de la Indústria in 1909 they played in five different stadiums. Those five stadiums were Velódromo de la Bonanova, Campo del Hotel Casanovas, Campo de la Plaza de las Armas, Campo de la Carretera de Horta, Campo de la Calle Muntaner.

Source: *[estadiosdeespana.com](http://www.estadiosdeespana.com/posts/barcelona-camp-de-les-corts/)*